# Outputting Json string?

Tags: json, httpresponse

I just want to create the following Json output as a HttpResponse:

```
{ "status": "OK", "verified": true }
```

But for some reason keep getting an error.

Comment: explain...you gave us what you want instead of the actual code..

Comment: This is a terrible question. Not only do you not even provide the code language, I assume a server side language, but you don't even let us know what the actual error is.

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out. I did this:

```
results= [{"status": "INVALID_REQUEST", "verified": False}]         
return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(results), mimetype='application/json')
```

Why wouldnt this work aswell?

```
results= [{"status": "INVALID_REQUEST", "verified": False}]
output = serializers.serialize('json', results, indent=2)
return HttpResponse(output, mimetype='application/json')
```